# com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder SecurityException: signer information does not match

Tags: java, azure, eclipse, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Im trying to execute a sample asynchronous mq call using the example from azure's service bus client using eclipse IDE. However im getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.SendMessageAsyncSample.run(SendMessageAsyncSample.java:51)
at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.SendMessageAsyncSample.main(SendMessageAsyncSample.java:27)
```

This is my java class which i have taken from Microsoft's website.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/SendMessageAsyncSample.java

```
package com.azure.messaging.servicebus;

import com.azure.core.util.BinaryData;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Sample demonstrates how to send a {@link ServiceBusMessage} to an Azure Service Bus 
  queue.
*/
public class SendMessageAsyncSample {

static String connectionString = "test";
static String queueName = "uat.recq";

/**
 * Main method to invoke this demo on how to send a {@link ServiceBusMessageBatch} to an Azure Service Bus.
 *
 * @param args Unused arguments to the program.
 * @throws InterruptedException If the program is unable to sleep while waiting for the operations to complete.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SendMessageAsyncSample sample = new SendMessageAsyncSample();
    sample.run();
}


public void run() throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicBoolean sampleSuccessful = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    CountDownLatch countdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // The connection string value can be obtained by:
    // 1. Going to your Service Bus namespace in Azure Portal.
    // 2. Go to "Shared access policies"
    // 3. Copy the connection string for the "RootManageSharedAccessKey" policy.
    // The 'connectionString' format is shown below.
    // 1. "Endpoint={fully-qualified-namespace};SharedAccessKeyName={policy-name};SharedAccessKey={key}"
    // 2. "<<fully-qualified-namespace>>" will look similar to "{your-namespace}.servicebus.windows.net"
    // 3. "queueName" will be the name of the Service Bus queue instance you created
    //    inside the Service Bus namespace.

    // Instantiate a client that will be used to call the service.
    ServiceBusSenderClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectionString)
        .sender()
        .queueName(queueName)
        .buildClient();

    // Create a message to send.
    final ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = sender.createMessageBatch();
    IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(index -> new ServiceBusMessage(BinaryData.fromString("Hello world! " + index)))
        .forEach(message -> messageBatch.tryAddMessage(message));

    // Send that message. It completes successfully when the event has been delivered to the Service queue or topic.
    // It completes with an error if an exception occurred while sending the message.
    sender.sendMessages(messageBatch);

    // Close the sender.
    sender.close();
  }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Azure</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
      <version>7.13.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to remove all the names and signatures in the MANIFEST.MF files

```
Name: com/azure/messaging/servicebus/implementation/Messages.java
SHA-256-Digest: r2j4hEvfoypLiEsKreoUQD94jZyJaz0yByg1u1w7CTo=
```

But I got the following error upon running the class.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest 
for Manifest main attributes
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:318)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:977)
at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.SendMessageAsyncSample.run(SendMessageAsyncSample.java:48)
at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.SendMessageAsyncSample.main(SendMessageAsyncSample.java:27)
```

I have tried running mvn dependency:tree but there are no visible conflicts.

```
[WARNING] Parameter 'localRepository' is deprecated core expression; Avoid use of 
ArtifactRepository type. If you need access to local repository, switch to '
${repositorySystemSession}' expression and get LRM from it instead.
[INFO] com.example:Azure:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] \- com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:jar:7.13.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.38.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.azure:azure-json:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.27:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.azure:azure-core-amqp:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.microsoft.azure:qpid-proton-j-extensions:jar:1.2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.qpid:proton-j:jar:0.33.8:compile
[INFO]    +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-x86_64:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-aarch_64:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-x86_64:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-aarch_64:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:windows-x86_64:2.0.56.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.89.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.28:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO]       +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

The following are my jar files in the JRE library & Maven Dependencies

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\charsets.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jce.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfr.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jsse.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\resources.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\rt.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar

C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\azure\azure-core\1.38.0\azure-core-1.38.0.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\azure\azure-core-amqp\2.8.4\azure-core-amqp-2.8.4.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\azure\azure-core-http-netty\1.13.2\azure-core-http-netty-1.13.2.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\azure\azure-json\1.0.0\azure-json-1.0.0.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\azure\azure-messaging-servicebus\7.13.4\azure-messaging-servicebus-7.13.4.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.5\jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.5\jackson-core-2.13.5.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.5\jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.13.5\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.13.5.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.5.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.89.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.89.Final\netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-dns\4.1.89.Final\netty-codec-dns-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.89.Final\netty-codec-http2-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.89.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.89.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.89.Final\netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.89.Final\netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.89.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.89.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver-dns\4.1.89.Final\netty-resolver-dns-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos\4.1.89.Final\netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver-dns-native-macos\4.1.89.Final\netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.89.Final-osx-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final-linux-aarch_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final-linux-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final-osx-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.56.Final-windows-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-classes\2.0.56.Final\netty-tcnative-classes-2.0.56.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-epoll\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-kqueue\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.89.Final-linux-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.89.Final-osx-x86_64.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.89.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.89.Final.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\org\apache\qpid\proton-j\0.33.8\proton-j-0.33.8.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\qpid-proton-j-extensions\1.2.4\qpid-proton-j-extensions-1.2.4.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.4\reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.4.27\reactor-core-3.4.27.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\netty\reactor-netty-core\1.0.28\reactor-netty-core-1.0.28.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\netty\reactor-netty-http\1.0.28\reactor-netty-http-1.0.28.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\4.2.1\stax2-api-4.2.1.jar
C:\Users\test.co\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\woodstox\woodstox-core\6.4.0\woodstox-core-6.4.0.jar
```

How do I bypass this problem as i am trying to switch from IBM MQ to Azure Service Bus Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the signing conflict is due to using the namespace name “com.azure.messaging.servicebus” for the sample, which is same as the Azure Service Bus Sdk namespace. Can you try changing it for the sample, say “com.example”?